# Slide up div from another divs top when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have 2 div as shown in below code.

What I just want is to slide up the second div (box-2) from the top of the first div.
The real problem is

- First div will remain as it is and second div will slide from it's back side.
- I want to keep the second div hidden and let it slide and revel it self as it slides i.e. only the portion that slides up should be visible.

Not sure how to do it, tried multiple options but no luck.
Really appreciate if anyone can guide.

```js
$('.box-2').animate({'margin-bottom': '83px'}, 3000);
```

```css
.box-1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;  
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.box-2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;  
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-1">div 1</div>

<div class="box-2">div 2 - the one that will slide up from box-1's Top.</div>
```

Comment: if you have `div-1` and `div-2`, and you need to show `div-1` above `div-2`, You should use `z-index` at css .. see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: nope, what I want is different,  initially box-2 should be hidden, then it should slide up from box-1's top and only the portion that slides should be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, considering your starting point, is to simply use the callback function exposed inside of the `animate()` method, which will be executed once the initial animation is completed:

```js
// your initial jQuery, which selects the '.box-2' element(s) and
// passes that collection to the animate() method:
$('.box-2').animate({
  // here rather than quote (just to show the example), we camel case
  // the CSS 'margin-bottom' property to the (unquoted) 'marginBottom',
  // and pass in the new dimension to which the method will animate:
  marginBottom: '83px'
// we then take advantage of the completion callback, which is called
// when the first animation is complete:
}, 1500, function() {
  // here we take the 'this' from the collection passed to the outer
  // animate() call in which this callback function is wrapped:
  $(this).animate({
    // here we then animate the 'width' to its new dimension of
    // '500px':
    width: '500px'
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
.box-1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.box-2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-2">Div that will slide up from box-1's Top.</div>

<div class="box-1">Static div</div>
```

Note that, because of the two animations running sequentially I divided your initial time of 3000ms to have each animation take 1500ms, so that the overall time taken is the same but allowing the animation to run in stages.

References:

- [`animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Thanks David. seems like this is the way.

Let me try it out.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help; give it a go and let us know if there are any problems.

Comment: here is what my functionality looks like https://jsfiddle.net/9joycrb8/1/. using your help, I was able to achieve the functionality I needed but just want to confirm that is there any way we can keep background transparent or achieve same functionality without using background div. (check #chat-symbole-container which has red bg) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `$( ".box-2" ).hide(0);` method is used to hide the second container after the animation. `z-index: -1;` style applied to make the `box-2` container appear at the bottom during animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* The animation moves the second container from the bottom to a height of 83px. */
    
    $('.box-2').animate({'margin-bottom': '83px'}, 3000, function(){
        /* The first container appears when the animation is finished. */
        $( ".box-1" ).css("display", "inline");
        
        /* The second container is stored after the animation. */
        $( ".box-2" ).hide(0);
    });
});
```

```css
.box-1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;  
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  
  /* The first container is initially hidden. */
  display: none;
}

.box-2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;  
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  
  /* Implemented to make the container appear at the bottom during animation. */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box-1">Static div</div>
<div class="box-2">Div that will slide up from box-1's Top.</div>
```

---

###### References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: thanks but what I really want is to have first div as it is and update second div. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question completely.

But if you want to reveal the box-2 from behind box-1, don't you just have to switch their positions in the html? So that box-1 is always in front of box-2

```js
$('.box-2').animate({'margin-bottom': '83px'}, 3000);
```

```css
.box-1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;  
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.box-2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;  
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-2">Div that will slide up from box-1's Top.</div>

<div class="box-1">Static div</div>
```

Comment: the main thing is initially box-2 should be hidden, then it should slide up from box-1's top and only the portion that slides should be visible.

Comment: What do you mean by "only the portion that slides should be visible"? The whole box is supposed to slide in from the bottom, isn't it? 

Maybe you can explain the use case to understand the goal here a little better

Comment: second box should start sliding up from the top of the first box.
initially it should be hidden and then when it slides, it should become visible. makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index:1;` on css of `.box-1`

```js
$('.box-2').animate({'margin-bottom': '83px'}, 3000);
```

```css
.box-1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;  
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index:1;
}

.box-2 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: blue;  
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box-1">div 1</div>

<div class="box-2">div 2 - the one that will slide up from box-1's Top.</div>
```